# Changes in correlation between two variables in VAR model after differencing

Tags: time-series, correlation, stationarity, vector-autoregression, differencing

I am building a VAR model with two variables.

When I used it with non-stationary data with strong trend and seasonality, the correlation between variables was `0.48`.

I did the first order differencing and one variable looks stationary now (the second looks stationary after the 2nd order differencing), but the correlation dropped to `0.16`.

Interestingly enough, when I did the differencing of the second order, the correlation decreased slightly - from `0.16` to `0.13`.

Cannot find anything about it. What is the intuition behind? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possibility is that the original correlation was due to the trend term.

Suppose for example,

$$
x_t = t + \epsilon_t
$$
$$
y_t = t + \eta_t
$$

where $\epsilon_t$ and $\eta_t$ are independent noise.
Then these two series are non-stationary due to the trend term and they are correlated, with the degree depending on the variance of the noise.

When you take the first difference, then

$$
\Delta x_t = 1 + \Delta \epsilon_t
$$
$$
\Delta y_t = 1 + \Delta \eta_t
$$

The two series are now stationary (under some appropriate assumptions about the noise).  Clearly, the two series are not correlated anymore.

Comment: Thanks for your time and explanation!